# Am I worrying too much?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith

Assalamu alaikum brother,
My friends ( of course Muslim friends) always keep telling me that I worry too much about Islamic rules in each and every scenario. For example, when they are downloading pirated software or games I am worrying that it could be considered as stealing in Islam,. When they are talking about investing in LIC I am worrying that is halal or Haram etc . Is my concern about applying Islamic rules in each and every decision and worrying whether it could be A sin. Could it be considered as wearing too much unnecessary.

Answer (score -2):

All those rules have their sense. It is however good to understand the sense of those rules. Sometimes, those rules are taken as forbidding something that was not really meant; I think of the rule not to depict humans or animals that was intended to prevent us from worshipping in front of those, now extended to not read or draw comics.

The rules you mention do have their sense, and it software piratery is haram because peaple want to live on selling it, and several work-arounds capitalism are in the sense haram, too, even if manypeople do not want to hear that, because it leads to inequity. God made thos rules for us, not we made the rules for God.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that this answer is not compliant orthodox teaching. However, the question was about in how far it is necessary to observe this teaching. So, my Point is that a different approach is possible inside Islam, but the outcome is not always less restrivtive than the orthodox teaching.